# How to insert buttons behind a fixed button

Tags: jquery, button

Hello I have set of data from a php, example( US, JAP, EUR, HK) and I want to put it behind a fix button.

When I use ('#heed').after it just put the buttons inside the All button
What command is the correct one to use?

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
       init();
       bull();
       function init() {
           set(); 
       }
   });
   function set() {
       var strLink  = '';
       strLink = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/portal/xxxxxxx.php?COUNT=XXX';
       $.ajax({ 
           dataType: "json",
           url: strLink,     
           success: showme, 
           async: false
       });
   }
   function showme ( data ) { 
       var strComname = '' ;

       for ( i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i ++ ) 
           KBLINK = data[i]['NEWS_LINK'];
           strComname = strComname + '<input type="submit" value="' +data[i]['NEWS_CATEGORY'] + '"'+ 'data-inline="true" />'  ;     
       }        
       $('#headlist').html(strComname) ;
       $('#headlist').listview("refresh") ; 
   }
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="page_main">
   <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Result</h1>

      <form id='headlist'>
          <button incline="true" id='heed'>ALL</button>
      </form>
   </div>
<div data-role="content">

<ul data-role="listview" id='main'>
    <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
</ul>   

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `behind a fix button`??preceeding or succeeding??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DIV tag in the form where you can add the button dynamically like this:

Replace the form tag with this:

```
<form id='headlist'>
<button incline="true" id='heed'>ALL</button>
<div id='btnAdd'>
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript to add the button to DIV tag:

```
$('#btnAdd').html('<button incline="true" id="newBtn">New Button</button>');
```